# Why are we able to find the closed form of each number of the form $ζ(2n)$, but struggling with numbers of the form $β(2n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

It is known that we are able to find the closed form of each number of the form $ζ(2n)$, but why are we struggling with numbers of the form $β(2n)$ (Dirichlet Beta function), even though they are very similar series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has a closed form for positive *odd* integers $2k+1$,
namely
$$
\beta (2k+1)={{{({-1})^{k}}{E_{{2k}}}{\pi ^{{2k+1}}} \over {4^{{k+1}}}(2k)!}},$$
where

$E_{{n}}$ represent the Euler numbers.

For even integers, a representation is more difficult, as follows.

For every positive integer $k$ we have
$$
{\displaystyle \beta (2k)={\frac {1}{2(2k-1)!}}\sum _{m=0}^{\infty }\left(\left(\sum _{l=0}^{k-1}{\binom {2k-1}{2l}}{\frac {(-1)^{l}A_{2k-2l-1}}{2l+2m+1}}\right)-{\frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{2m+2k}}\right){\frac {A_{2m}}{(2m)!}}{\left({\frac {\pi }{2}}\right)}^{2m+2k},}
$$

where
${\displaystyle A_{k}}$ is the Euler zigzag number.

So the situation is exactly the same as for $\zeta(s)$, only with "even" and "odd" interchanged, where we have a closed formula for $\zeta(2n)$.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I intend something different when I say "closed form": what I meant is, like what we can do with even positive values for the Zeta function (Solutions in terms of pi multiplied with a real number), why are we not able to do a similar thing with even values for the Dirichlet Beta function, even though they are so similar?

Comment: But we *are* able to do it, it is only interchanged. Even and odd can be different, for different but similar functions. So $\zeta(2n)$ "corresponds" to $\beta(2n+1)$ in this respect.

Comment: Interesting. Then, last question: why were positive even values of the Zeta function easier to find, compared to odd positive values?

Comment: Because of the definition of $\zeta(s)$. Residue calculus then shows that it is easy to derive a nice formula for $\zeta(2n)$, while the nature of the numbers $\zeta(2n+1)$ is much more difficult to understand. Have a look at the proof for the formula of $\zeta(2n)$ to see, why we need even integers.